# UIPreviewAction which does the same as a "pop" after "peek"

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I would like to add a preview action like "Open item", which does the same, as force pressing the peeked ViewController: just show the ViewController.

The UIPreviewActionItem array is queried on the ViewController I want to show, so getting the instance of the viewController is not a problem (as it is "self"), but how do I get to the ViewController, which originated the peek and pop, so that I can call "showViewController". Or is there a better way to achieve the task of just "finishing" the peek and pop action using an UIPreviewAction?